# React: Change big calendar onNavigate trigger from clicking the date number to the whole cell date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-big-calendar

I am currently using the Big Calendar on React. Currently, Big Calendar triggers its onNavigate callback when you click on the date in the cell.

[image]

What I want is to make onNavigate fire when I click the whole cell of date.

[image]

Is there a possible way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `view`, `onView`, `date`, and `onNavigate`, doing `view` and `date` as controlled props, then you could use your `onSelectSlot` prop to change your `date`.

```
const handleSlotSelect = slotInfo => {
  if (view === 'month') { // assumes you got 'view' from state
    // ... do some date stuff to get _just the date_ from the slotInfo.start
    handleNavigate(newDate);
    handleViewChange('day');
  }
  // ... any other slot selection functionality for other views
};
```

Bear in mind that doing this will not call RBC's internal `handleViewChange`, `onNavigate`, or `handleRangeChange` methods. Also best if you're using function components with the `useState` hooks here, so that your state updates are bundled together, so `date` and `view` are updated simultaneously.

Comment: Hi Steve. Thank you for the response! I will try this solution and update you with the results.

Comment: @nypogi Hope it helps. Don't forget to 'Up' the answer here, so other's know it works for you.